# Getting "Non-static method should not be called statically" error when export to Excel in Laravel

Tags: excel, laravel

Web:

```
Route::get('/export', 'ExportController@export');
```

ExportController:

```
public function export() {
    return Excel::download(new UserExport, 'users.xlsx');
}
```

UserExport:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;

public function collection() {
    return User::all();
}
```

The App:

```
'Excel' => Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,
Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class, (provider)
```

Getting this error:

> Non-static method Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::download() should not be called statically

What am I doing wrong ?)

Answer (score 0):

Change your export method to this and I hope it works

```
public function export(){
    $export = new Excel();
    return $export->download(new UserExport, 'users.xlsx');
}
```

**Not tested**

Comment: it didn't work.                                                                    ArgumentCountError
Too few arguments to function Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::__construct(), 0 passed in E:\Xampp\htdocs\Projects\laravel\HappyOutlets\app\Http\Controllers\ExportController.php on line 14 and exactly 4 expected

Comment: @Don can you access Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel.php file ?

Comment: whenever I type Excel in  my code editor (vscode) it automatically detects Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel instead  of Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel also version is "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1"